# docker-compose / wordpress permissions error for volume mount

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

my **docker-compose.yml**

```
wordpress:
  image: wordpress
  links:
    - wordpress_db:mysql
  ports:
    - 8080:80
  volumes:
    - /tmp/html/:/var/www/html
wordpress_db:
  image: mysql:5.6.29
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
phpmyadmin:
  image: corbinu/docker-phpmyadmin
  links:
    - wordpress_db:mysql
  ports:
    - 8181:80
  environment:
    MYSQL_USERNAME: root
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
```

when I do

**sudo /usr/local/bin/docker-compose up**

I'm getting a lot of these

```
wordpress_1     | tar: ./wp-content/plugins/akismet/views/stats.php: Cannot open: No such file or directory
wordpress_1     | tar: ./wp-content: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
wordpress_1     | tar: ./wp-content/plugins/akismet/wrapper.php: Cannot open: No such file or directory
wordpress_1     | tar: ./wp-content: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
wordpress_1     | tar: ./wp-content/plugins/akismet/.htaccess: Cannot open: No such file or directory
wordpress_1     | tar: ./wp-content: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
wordpress_1     | tar: ./wp-content/plugins/akismet/class.akismet-widget.php: Cannot open: No such file or directory
wordpress_1     | tar: ./wp-content: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
wordpress_1     | tar: ./wp-content/plugins/akismet/class.akismet-admin.php: Cannot open: No such file or directory
wordpress_1     | tar: ./wp-content: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
wordpress_1     | tar: ./wp-content/plugins/akismet/class.akismet.php: Cannot open: No such file or directory
wordpress_1     | tar: ./wp-content: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
wordpress_1     | tar: ./wp-content/plugins/akismet/readme.txt: Cannot open: No such file or directory
wordpress_1     | tar: ./wp-content: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
wordpress_1     | tar: ./wp-content/plugins/akismet/index.php: Cannot open: No such file or directory
wordpress_1     | tar: ./wp-content: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
wordpress_1     | tar: ./wp-content/plugins/akismet/_inc: Cannot mkdir: No such file or directory
wordpress_1     | tar: ./wp-content: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
wordpress_1     | tar: ./wp-content/plugins/akismet/_inc/img: Cannot mkdir: No such file or directory
wordpress_1     | tar: ./wp-content: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
wordpress_1     | tar: ./wp-content/plugins/akismet/_inc/img/logo-full-2x.png: Cannot open: No such file or directory
wordpress_1     | tar: ./wp-content: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
wordpress_1     | tar: ./wp-content/plugins/akismet/_inc/form.js: Cannot open: No such file or directory
wordpress_1     | tar: ./wp-content: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
wordpress_1     | tar: ./wp-content/plugins/akismet/_inc/akismet.css: Cannot open: No such file or directory
wordpress_1     | tar: ./wp-content: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
wordpress_1     | tar: ./wp-content/plugins/akismet/_inc/akismet.js: Cannot open: No such file or directory
wordpress_1     | tar: ./wp-content: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
wordpress_1     | tar: ./wp-content/plugins/akismet/akismet.php: Cannot open: No such file or directory
wordpress_1     | tar: ./wp-content: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
wordpress_1     | tar: ./wp-content/plugins/akismet/LICENSE.txt: Cannot open: No such file or directory
wordpress_1     | tar: ./wp-content: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
wordpress_1     | tar: ./wp-content/index.php: Cannot open: No such file or directory
wordpress_1     | tar: ./wp-trackback.php: Cannot open: Permission denied
wordpress_1     | tar: ./wp-links-opml.php: Cannot open: Permission denied
wordpress_1     | tar: ./wp-cron.php: Cannot open: Permission denied
wordpress_1     | tar: ./wp-signup.php: Cannot open: Permission denied
wordpress_1     | tar: .: Cannot utime: Permission denied
wordpress_1     | tar: .: Cannot change ownership to uid 33, gid 33: Permission denied
wordpress_1     | tar: .: Cannot change mode to rwxr-xr-x: Permission denied
wordpress_1     | tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

any ideas?

I set 777 to /tmp/html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the permission denied part, this could be linked to:

- the host (on Windows or ac, only C:\Users or /Users is mounted by the Linux VirtualHost)
  That would make `/tmp` empty, resulting in an empty `/var/www/html`.
- the Linux sec policy (see [`docker-library/wordpress` issue 132](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/132#issuecomment-201167278)) if you are directly on a Linux host.

> The problem is that `setenforce 0` works differently on Fedora and CentOS

Comment: yeah the problem was in selinux, once in permissive mode  it worked